# Remove a line from a .txt line on grep match in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

So I'm fairly new to Shell scripting and trying to build a function that deletes a line from a .txt file.

To be clear I want to be able to run the following command

```
$ ./script.sh searchTerm delete
```

Which should find the line containing 'searchTerm' and remove it.

I am passing the $1 (to capture the searchTerm) into the deletePassword function but can't seem to get it to work.

Would love some advice :)

```
#Delete a password
if [[ $2 == "delete" ]]; then
    deletePassword $1
fi

function deletePassword () {
    line=grep -Hrn $1 pwstore.txt
    sed -n $line pwstore.txt 
    echo "Deleted that for you.."
}
```

When running the previous command I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "pwstore.txt": extra characters at the end of p command
```

Comment: `Would love some advice :)` -- Please read about command substitution, variable quoting, ...

Comment: `grep -v "searchTerm" < oldfile.txt > newfile.txt; mv newfile.txt oldfile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `line` variable isn't being set as you expect, as you need to use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to capture the result of a command like that. eg:

```
line=$(grep -Hrn $1 pwstore.txt)
```

I would suggest just using `sed` instead:

```
sed -i.bak "/$1/d" pwstore.txt
```

This will delete any lines which match the string stored in `$1` from pwstore.txt (and create a backup of the original file at pwstore.txt.bak)

Comment: Thanks so much - great idea with the backup also :)